# Javascript list/steak

Tags: javascript

Is there a function in javascript to take the fist element? There is push - that put element to the end and I need function to take from the begining (with next destruction), so my array will work as FIFO list/steak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

This removes the first element of the array and returns it.

It's frequently used for queue handling

```
var fun;
while (fun=queue.shift()) fun();
```

Comment: Yes, push/pop for a stack (LIFO), push/shift for a queue (FIFO).

Answer (score 1):

You can use splice like this:

```
obj = arr.splice(0,1)[0];
```

It will remove the first element and place it in the var obj.